# can't rebuild on node-gyp even though I installed its dependencies

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I followed option 1 at [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) I installed

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

and install node-gyp global but I have this error below that I cannot fix

[image]

node-gyp configure runs ok but i cannot run rebuild. help?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post an answer as this might help someone else, I stated that I followed option 1 at node-gyp since it's for windows and I am using windows 10 and it's all correct, if you see my error on the image i posted, it is originating from .node-gyp file, delete it and node-gyp rebuild again, so just follow the option 1 on node-gyp requirements then run node-gyp rebuild again